# Why was my suggested edit that added details from comments rejected?

Tags: discussion, rejected-edits

[Review of suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/24755592)

The OP clarified what they were asking for in a comment response so I added those details to help direct the question to people who could help answer.

Any insight so I can better understand the process, or not waste my time, would be appreciated.

Comment: 2 people weren't paying attention when they reviewed it?  I see nothing wrong.

Comment: Looks reasonable to me. Maybe the reviewers didn't notice your edit summary.

Comment: I've applied your change (also I don't think it was useful enough to make as suggested edit)... but question looks like product search request to me...

Comment: Google "turd polishing" to learn more.

Comment: @HansPassant you mean https://youtu.be/3rax27_ZIVM?t=150 :)?

Comment: Your edit didn't make question any clearer nor more on topic. If you had editing privileges then making such edit on unclosed questions would be fine. Since you don't have them, insignificant edits are not encouraged because they require participation from other members.